# Why would resources.getStringArray(int) throw exception?

Tags: java, android, exception, resources

I have a call to

```
Resources resources = Resources.getSystem();
String[] networkFiles = resources.getStringArray(R.array.xmlNetworkFiles);
```

and I know this resource array exists (since I can reference it with the auto generated R file) but yet it continues to throw `ResourceNotFoundException`.

**What could be causing this and what can I do to fix this?**

I have used similar code elsewhere for retrieving an array of ints, but this one always fails in my unit tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `Resources.getSystem()` returns the wrong Resources object. From the documentation:

> Return a global shared Resources
>   object that provides access to only
>   system resources (no application
>   resources), and is not configured for
>   the current screen (can not use
>   dimension units, does not change based
>   on orientation, etc).

So although `R.array.xmlNetworkFiles` is a defined resource value for your application, you're asking for a system resource and it's not being found.

Use `getResource()` (from an Activity subclass) or `getContext().getResources()` (from a View class) instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
Resources resources = getResources();
String[] networkFiles = resources.getStringArray(R.array.xmlNetworkFiles);
```

Try this, I think this may solve your issue.

Comment: This will not work if the class is not subclass of the Activity or Service